# Artifactory configuring Tomcat server for SSL

Tags: artifactory

I am a newbie to Artifactory and I have installed the OSS ver. 7.31.13 build of Artifactory from repo as outlined in Artifactory install guide. I'm trying to configure the bundled Tomcat server for SSL by using the config options in the system.yaml file.  Here is what I am setting in the system.yaml file:

```
httpsConnector:
        ## Enable connector with SSL/TLS
        enabled: true
        ## Port to use for the HTTPS connector
        port: 8443
        ## Certificate file to use
        #certificateFile: "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/jfa.cer"
        certificateFile: "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/server.crt"
        ## Certificate key file to use.
        #certificateKeyFile: "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/jfa.key"
        certificateKeyFile: "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/server.key"
        ## Extra configuration for the HTTPS connector.
        ## For example extraConfig: "SSLProtocol='TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2'"
        extraConfig: "SSLProtocol='TLSv1.2'"
```

I have wanted to add more extra options, i.e. Ciphers to use and to "honor" the order of the Cipher listed.  But right now I'm just trying to get SSL working.  At one point, ports 8081 and 8082 disappeared along with no reference to port 8443 and/or the certificate and private key showing in any log files, even the catalina files that are generated for Tomcat.  When I "pared" back on the configuration, i.e. only specifiying SSLProtocol only, I was able to get ports 8081 and 8082 to show again, but still no port 8443.  I've also specified a different certificate and key file by copying my certificate and private key to new names, thinking that these names need to match what is in the template file.  This configuration seems relatively straight forward, but its like I'm missing something.
Any assistance you are able to provide would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric. :)

Comment: Please read [tour]. SO is for programming questions. For Server related questions there is an other SE site, [server fault]

Answer (score 1):

See the following article from JFrog [about custom certificates](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+Access+as+a+Certificate+Authority) and follow the steps in there.
Please pay special attention to the section **Custom Certificate and CA Prerequisites** and validate your certificate following the prerequisites.

If you wish to debug the issue, you can check out for warning\errors on the following logs

```
$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/artifactory/log/router-service.log
$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/artifactory/log/access-service.log
```

Comment: Please do not answer to off-topi questions, instead guide newer users to use SO accoridingly. SO is for programming questions